# HowTo test module export branch?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jasmine

I have in my `server/config/environment/index.coffee` such code:

```
module.exports = _.merge(all, require('./' + process.env.NODE_ENV + '.js') or {})
```

How would you test the `|| {}` branch?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to deconstruct the statement. Require will throw an error if it does not find the file, so you will need to wrap it in a try/catch.

To test it you would have to set NODE_ENV to a value you don't have a file for.

A much better alternative is just to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/config.
it does all this out of the box, with additional support for local overrides.
I use it on almost all my projects.